# Metodos JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

`forEach` / `slice.Call()` / `[].slice()`

Alguém pode me dar uma breve explicação desses métodos, e quando eu posso usa-los?

Comment: Você já tem os métodos e quer um problema? Seria mais interessante você trazer um problema para a gente te orientar sobre quais métodos se aplicam. De qualquer forma, dê uma olhada na [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/).

Comment: Espero ter lançado alguma luz à tua pergunta. Talvez surjam novas perguntas desta explicação. Tenta separá-las e caso não encontres resposta coloca uma nova per4gunta, mais específica que esta :)

Comment: Pedro aqui também podes aceitar a resposta, ou pedir esclarecimentos caso não esteja claro. Se não souberes como fazer dá uma olhada aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/129

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deves ter em conta que os métodos do jQuery são para aplicar a coleções jQuery e não a arrays/objetos nativos.

#### `.forEach()`

O [`.forEach(el, index)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) não é um método jQuery. Ele é sim um método nativo do JavaScript introduzido na versão ES5. O correspondente do jQuery para este método é o [`.each(index, el)`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) que tem os argumentos da callback invertidos, e passa o `el` como contexto à callback.

Este método (ambos a versão nativa e a do jQuery) são iteradores. Servem para percorrer uma array ou coleção jQuery.

#### `.slice()`

Este método existe no jQuery e também no JavaScript nativo. Mais uma vez eles são semelhantes e fazem a mesma coisa, respectivamente em coleções jQuery ou arrays nativas.

O método [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) em sí, serve para criar cópias de pedaços de uma array/coleção.

#### O que faz `.call()` ou `[].slice.call()`?

Os métodos que descrevi em cima (e muitos outros também) têm um método interno que é o `.call()`. Esse método permite chamar o `slice`, `forEach` ou outro passando como contexto o primeiro argumento que esse método receber. Lembras-te que referí que o `.forEach` do jQuery se chama `.each` e passa o elemento da coleção como contexto? ou seja o `this` dentro da callback... Pois, o que o jQuery faz é chamar `.each.call(el, etc...`.

A ideia aqui é poder chamar uma função ou método controlando o contexto em que vai ser corrido.

Usar `[].slice.call` é basicamente o mesmo que `Array.prototype.slice.call`, mas mais curto :) E permite converter Listas em arrays. Listas não são arrays, mas podem ser convertidas em arrays. Um exemplo de uma Lista é o resultado de `document.querySelectorAll('div');`, que não têm um método `.forEach` mas pode ser iterado se usado assim:

```
var divs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div'));
// e depois:
divs.forEach(function(el){
    // fazer algo sobre o elemento <div> a ser iterado
});
```